# wp twenty eleven header oddity

Tags: css, wordpress

Wordpress theme twenty-eleven.
I have twisted myself into a little mystery. Pardon for poss. stupid question.

Something in the header is altering the placement/height of my h1 on *some* pages.
Note the difference in height in the index and - say - fuel
Index: http://qfsltd.no/

It is not an issue of page versus post-containing-pages. I had it working for a while, but then mysterious problem is back. It seems to be above the header, right up at the top, but I cannot "get hold" of what div (?) it is creating the issue.

I simply cannot figure it out, and have tried a million things. Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the body class  is override some rules in some case, for example, line 33

```
body, body.blog, body.page-id-11, body.page-id-67
```

delete the line for `line-height` and you will see the diference

Comment: AH! saviour! many, many thanks. That was indeed the ticket. May I ask how you figured it out so quickly?

Comment: I played with firebug (firefox plugin) to see what was the problem.